# UIAlertView with buttons, title overlapping?

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview

I've an alert view with 4 buttons and a title. It works fine on iOS 7, but on iOS 6 the title overlaps the first button.
How can I solve?
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: Here is the code:

```
UIAlertView * dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
dialog.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
[dialog setTitle:@"These are your choices"];
[dialog setMessage:@""];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 1"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 2"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 3"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[dialog show];
```

And here the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
-(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
float currentVersion = 7.0;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < currentVersion)
{
    [alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(alertView.frame.origin.x, alertView.frame.origin.y -20, alertView.frame.size.width, alertView.frame.size.height + 45)];
    for (UIView *view in alertView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            CGRect rect=view.frame;
            rect.origin.y += 45;
            view.frame = rect;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a bug when you add buttons after initialization in iOS 6. Add the buttons in the `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` initializer and you should be fine.

Comment: I agree. The technique @charles is using is to be avoided in any case; who would anyone _not_ call `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` to begin with?

Comment: Same problem also with this initializer.

Comment: @matt: It could be useful if button titles are dynamic or variable.

Comment: @charles: Do it with the title and message as well. Something tells me they don't recalculate the frame after modifying the content if you just alloc/init the alert.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Yes but I said "to begin with". You form the basic alert with `initWithTitle:...` - always. There is never a reason to call plain `init` here.

Comment: @matt: Gotcha, absolutely true.

Answer (score 0):

U can make your own alert view, on the xib, with 3 buttons.

It´s a little bit harder, but it should work in ios6 and 7.

It should be a subclass of UIView, and i recommend u to disable autolayout.

I hope it helps you.